# Download image from url Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a URL from firebase with a url but the thing is that it is not a url with the image directly but from that link it gets downloaded. How can i put the image into a normal image on the app.
Here is the link https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/beatact-287421.appspot.com/o/images%2F88DE845D-9DAE-4DF0-9F16-7A079E06C0DE.png?alt=media&token=cda0e9d0-8f5e-4af5-907d-e7cecff4af30

Comment: You can show it in a `Image.network(url)` widget.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Image.network(url)` widget to display the picture within the app.